# Miglayout or an alternative layout manager

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

i'm currently learning Java Swing and came across what I think is an interesting topic that I couldn't find an answer to online. So my question is i've got a JFrame using Miglayout but it's not working the way I would like it to. I'll post a picture of what it's currently looking like and what I want it to look like and i'll also post my code. Also, i've tried to put a JPanel on a JPanel and then move them around using Miglayout but that didn't work. Will Miglayout work with this or would another layout manager be better?

EDIT 
What I want it to look like is have a JTextArea and right next to it have 3 JRadioButtons grouped together but the radio button at the bottom of the stack reformats itself so it ends up at the bottom of the JTextArea

```
public SecondFrame() {
    formPanel.setLayout(new net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout());

    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(500, 525);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    //by adding the buttons to a group it will only allow you to select 1 button at a time
    buttonGroupLocation.add(sydney);
    buttonGroupLocation.add(melbourne);
    buttonGroupLocation.add(brisbane);

    buttonGroupSeverityLevels.add(lowSeverityBtn);
    buttonGroupSeverityLevels.add(mediumSeverityBtn);
    buttonGroupSeverityLevels.add(highSeverityBtn);
    buttonGroupSeverityLevels.add(criticalSeverityBtn);

    formPanel.add(sydney, "cell 0 0 1 1");
    formPanel.add(melbourne, "cell 0 1 1 1, wrap");
    formPanel.add(brisbane, "cell 0 2 1 1, wrap");

    formPanel.add(issue, "cell 1 0 1 1, wrap");
    formPanel.add(issueArea, "span ");

    formPanel.add(solution, "cell 0 8 1 1, wrap");
    formPanel.add(solutionArea, "cell 0 15 8 1");

    formPanel.add(severity, "cell 0 4 1 1, wrap");
    formPanel.add(lowSeverityBtn, "cell 0 5 1 1");
    formPanel.add(mediumSeverityBtn, "cell 1 5 1 1");
    formPanel.add(highSeverityBtn, "cell 2 5 1 1");
    formPanel.add(criticalSeverityBtn, "cell 3 5 1 1");

    formPanel.add(submit, "cell 0 16 1 1");
    formPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2,2,2,2));

    f.add(formPanel);

    formPanel.add(submit, "cell 0 16 1 1");
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you post an [MCVE] ?

Answer (score 1):

If `MigLayout` cannot do it, other layout managers will hardly do it.
For `MigLayout`, this is a piece of cake. There are several ways how
to accomplish your task. I have done it by placing the three radio
buttons into one cell. This can be done by splitting the cell into three
subcells.

```
package com.zetcode;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class MigLayoutAirportEx extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutAirportEx() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        setLayout(new MigLayout());

        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();

        JRadioButton sydn = new JRadioButton("Sydney");
        JRadioButton melb = new JRadioButton("Melbourne");
        JRadioButton bris = new JRadioButton("Brisbane");

        bg.add(sydn);
        bg.add(melb);
        bg.add(bris);

        JLabel issue = new JLabel("Issue");
        JTextArea area = new JTextArea(15, 20);
        area.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        add(sydn, "split 3, flowy, aligny top");        
        add(melb);
        add(bris);
        add(issue, "split 2, flowy");
        add(area, "push, grow, wrap");

        pack();

        setTitle("ARE - Airport Retail Enteprises");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }    


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            MigLayoutAirportEx ex = new MigLayoutAirportEx();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

The example creates the upper part of your UI where you have your issue.

> Also, i've tried to put a JPanel on a JPanel and then move them around
>   using Miglayout but that didn't work.

These are inherited bad habits from poor layout managers. With `MigLayout`, you do not need any additional panels with other layout managers. Powerful layout managers do not need this.

And here is the screenshot:

[image]